# Use theme mod value as default shortcode attr

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

So I have a simple map shortcode I made that used a theme mod I had already added for something else as the address (this is obviously not the whole thing but you get the picture):

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500" id="gmap_canvas" 
src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo get_theme_mod( 
'primary_location'); ?>&t=&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" frameborder="0" 
scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

Then I thought it should  include the option to set height and width including default values.  I also thought having the option to use a different location would be nice, so now it starts with:

```
function shortcode_map($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
'height' => '500px', 'width' => '500px', 'location' => ''
), $atts));

ob_start(); ?>

<iframe width="<?php echo esc_attr($width); ?>" height="<?php echo 
esc_attr($height); ?>" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q= 
<?php echo esc_attr($location); ?>&t=&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" 
frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

But I'd like the default location to still be the primary location and don't really know how to even begin to sort that out.

Comment: first, avoid to use `extract()` function. more you can see here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22400

Comment: also, it's unclear for me what you want to achieve. what is your question? make your question more detailed

Comment: I want the default location to be  <?php echo get_theme_mod( 
'primary_location'); ?>

Comment: so, use it. what is the problem?

Comment: so what exactly goes between `'location' => ''` if i knew the answer I wouldn't be asking the question

Comment: I see. so, you would to use `location` if it set, if no, then use default one, right?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working:

```
function shortcode_map($atts, $content = null) {

$location = get_theme_mod('primary_location');
extract(shortcode_atts(array('height' => '500px', 'width' => '500px', 
'location' => $location), $atts));
 ob_start(); ?>

<iframe width="<?php echo esc_attr($width); ?>" height="<?php echo 
esc_attr($height); ?>" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q= 
<?php echo esc_attr($location); ?>&t=&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" 
frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```